# Java Tetris - Using transpose to rotate a piece

Tags: java, swing, transpose, tetris

I'm building Tetris in Java as a fun side project and am now working on rotations.

I was originally hard coding each rotation which was proving to be quite tedious.

That being said, I was then going to try Matrix Rotations using linear algebra, but someone on the [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363602/java-tetris-using-rotation-matrix-math-to-rotate-piece) recommended I try transposing. So given his description, I tried drawing it out. Did I get the drawings correct?

[image]

From that, I'm not trying to code the transpose, but now am completely lost in my code.

```
public void getTranspose() {
    Tile[][] gridTranspose = transpose();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("B`:");
    for (int j = 0; j < gridTranspose.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridTranspose[j].length-1; i++) {
            System.out.print("(" + i + ", " + j + ") ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public Tile[][] transpose() {
    Tile gridT[][];
    gridT = new Tile[width][height];
    System.out.println("B:");
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length-1; j++) {
            System.out.print("(" + i + ", " + j + ") ");
            gridT[j][i] = grid[i][j]; 
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return gridT;   
}
```

This outputs a seemingly correct transposed graph?

**B:**

```
(0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2) (0, 3) (0, 4) (0, 5) (0, 6) (0, 7) (0, 8) 
(1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4) (1, 5) (1, 6) (1, 7) (1, 8) 
(2, 0) (2, 1) (2, 2) (2, 3) (2, 4) (2, 5) (2, 6) (2, 7) (2, 8) 
(3, 0) (3, 1) (3, 2) (3, 3) (3, 4) (3, 5) (3, 6) (3, 7) (3, 8) 
(4, 0) (4, 1) (4, 2) (4, 3) (4, 4) (4, 5) (4, 6) (4, 7) (4, 8) 
(5, 0) (5, 1) (5, 2) (5, 3) (5, 4) (5, 5) (5, 6) (5, 7) (5, 8) 
(6, 0) (6, 1) (6, 2) (6, 3) (6, 4) (6, 5) (6, 6) (6, 7) (6, 8) 
(7, 0) (7, 1) (7, 2) (7, 3) (7, 4) (7, 5) (7, 6) (7, 7) (7, 8) 
(8, 0) (8, 1) (8, 2) (8, 3) (8, 4) (8, 5) (8, 6) (8, 7) (8, 8) 
(9, 0) (9, 1) (9, 2) (9, 3) (9, 4) (9, 5) (9, 6) (9, 7) (9, 8)
```

**B`:**

```
(0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0) (3, 0) (4, 0) (5, 0) (6, 0) (7, 0) (8, 0) 
(0, 1) (1, 1) (2, 1) (3, 1) (4, 1) (5, 1) (6, 1) (7, 1) (8, 1) 
(0, 2) (1, 2) (2, 2) (3, 2) (4, 2) (5, 2) (6, 2) (7, 2) (8, 2) 
(0, 3) (1, 3) (2, 3) (3, 3) (4, 3) (5, 3) (6, 3) (7, 3) (8, 3) 
(0, 4) (1, 4) (2, 4) (3, 4) (4, 4) (5, 4) (6, 4) (7, 4) (8, 4) 
(0, 5) (1, 5) (2, 5) (3, 5) (4, 5) (5, 5) (6, 5) (7, 5) (8, 5) 
(0, 6) (1, 6) (2, 6) (3, 6) (4, 6) (5, 6) (6, 6) (7, 6) (8, 6) 
(0, 7) (1, 7) (2, 7) (3, 7) (4, 7) (5, 7) (6, 7) (7, 7) (8, 7) 
(0, 8) (1, 8) (2, 8) (3, 8) (4, 8) (5, 8) (6, 8) (7, 8) (8, 8) 
(0, 9) (1, 9) (2, 9) (3, 9) (4, 9) (5, 9) (6, 9) (7, 9) (8, 9)
```

So my questions are:

1) Is my drawing above a correct interpretation of his description?

2) Am I correctly generating a transposed graph?

3) If so, how should I paint the rotated block... Should I just replace `grid[row][col]` with `transpose()`?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            if(grid[row][col] != null) {
                //if there is a non-null space, that is a Tetris piece.. fill it red
                if (grid[row][col].getColor() != null) {
                    g.setColor(grid[row][col].getColor());
                    g.fillRect(row * tilesize, col * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g.drawString("(" + row + ", " + col + ")", row * tilesize, col * tilesize+10);
                }           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503290/java-tetris-rotation ?

Comment: What does `grid` represent? The entire playing area, including pieces previously placed? Or just the current piece?

Comment: @RobWatts the entire playing area. `grid = new Tile[width][height];`, and I set places on the grid null if there's no tile in that (x,y) location... At the start of the code I initialize a new piece which is composed for 4 tiles, `newPiece = new Piece(this, "Bar");`... since they have locations on grid, the paintComponent will see they're not null and paint them.

Answer (score 3):

Transposing alone won't work for all of the normal tetris pieces. For example, take the piece shaped like this:

```
xx_
_xx
___
```

When you transpose it, you end up with this:

```
x__
xx_
_x_
```

So rather than think about a particular piece, think about what happens when you work with a square with the corners labeled:

```
a_b
___
d_c
```

This make it very clear if your rotation is good or not. So let's look at transpose:

```
a_d
___
b_c
```

In order to get the clockwise rotation, we can just flip it sideways:

```
d_a
___
c_b
```

Performing the same operation again should give us a full half rotation from where we started. Take the transpose:

```
d_c
___
a_b
```

And flip it:

```
c_d
___
b_a
```

So in order to do a clockwise rotation, simply take the transpose and flip it. What happens if we do the opposite, flip it and then take the transpose? Working from the previous orientation, this is what we get if we flip it:

```
d_c
___
a_b
```

Now take the transpose:

```
d_a
___
c_b
```

And we're back to what we had after one rotate - a counterclockwise rotation. So transposing alone won't work, but transposing combined with a horizontal flip does everything you need!

As for your questions,

1. I'm not sure your drawing is a correct interpretation. Based on the comments you left I suspect that I may have misunderstood them, which is why I made the drawings above to show what needs to happen.
2. Yes, that is a correctly transposed graph. You probably don't want to use `gridTranspose[j].length-1` in the loops, as that cuts off one column.
3. To paint the rotated block, I would suggest having a separate variable for holding the current piece. If the piece were at `x,y`, then you would put something like this in your `paintComponent` method:

   ```
   for(int row = 0; row < piece.length(); row++) {
       for(int col = 0; col < piece.width(); piece++) {
           if(piece.hasBlockAt(row, col) {
               g.setColor(piece.getColorAt(row, col));
               g.fillRect((row+x) * tilesize, (col+y) * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);
           }
       } 
   }
   ```

Comment: Okay, then can you help me understand how I can use matrix rotations? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Common_rotations

Comment: Rob, the mirroring is what lewellen was talking about in the Mathematics.SE link I provided. I understand that, but was having trouble implementing it. EDIT: Is that your explanation of the Matrix Rotations I asked about? I don't get how Sin and Cos play into it though

Comment: No, this isn't using the matrix rotations

Comment: Rob I understand the transposing coupled with Mirroring. I stated 3 questions above. Can you review them please?